# jQuery: Get total of same string from table

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

i got a table with `td`'s that look like this:

> **Country | City | Number**
>
> Thailand | Phuket | 25
>
> Thailand | Bangkok | 12
>
> China | Wenzhou | 1
>
> Australia | Sydney | 2
>
> Vietnam | Saigon | 4
>
> China | Beijing | 3
>
> USA | New York | 4
>
> USA | Miami | 2

How can i get  a total for each country, ie Thailand = 37 (25+12), via jQuery (or plain JS)?
It would be simple if I could define each country however these values comes from a database and it can be over 50 countries/cities so need to put each in an array first and then somehow use inArray and add **Number** to already existing array if it exists.

Updated with jsfiddle: **http://bit.ly/1iizLAt**

Comment: Create an object whose properties are the country names. Loop through all the rows of the table, and add the number to the propery with that country.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript objects are essentially key/value maps, so you can track the total for the countries even though you don't know in advance what their names are:

To create the map:

```
var countryCounts = {};
```

I assume you can use the jQuery API to loop through the rows of the table, and get the country name for the row; let's say you put it in the variable `country`. Then, to count a time you've seen the country (in the loop):

```
countryCounts[country] = (countryCounts[country] || 0) + 1;
```

*(Note that this assumes there's no chance that a country will have the name of any of the properties that exist by default on `Object.prototype`, such as `toString` or `valueOf`.)*

That line looks a bit tricky, in two ways, so here's how it works:

1. You can look up a property name on an object *either* using dot notation and a property name literal, e.g., `obj.foo`, or by using bracketed notation and a *string*, e.g. `obj["foo"]`. In the latter case, the string can be the result of any expression. So if `country` is `"Thailand"`, `countryCounts[country]` looks up the property `Thailand` on `countryCounts`.
2. If you look up a propery that doesn't exist on the object, you get back `undefined`, which is a "falsey" value. JavaScript's [curiously-powerful `||` operator](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html) returns the first non-falsey (truthy) argument you give it. So `countryCounts[country] || 0` will give you `countryCounts[country]` if that value is truthy, or `0` if `countryCounts[country]` is falsey. So you end up with the current count for the country, or the number `0`. Then we add one to it and store it.

Then to loop through the results in `countryCounts`:

```
for (country in countryCounts) {
    if (countryCounts.hasOwnPropery(country)) {
        // Use `country` and `countryCounts[country]`

}
```

`for-in` loops through the names of the enumerable properties of an object. Using `hasOwnProperty` is a bit paranoid here, but it's good practice; it weeds out any enumerable properties that might exist on the object's prototype. (There are no enumerable properties on `Object.prototype`, and if you catch someone adding any you should give them a Severe Talking To, but still it's good practice.)

---

In the comments below, ajax333221 suggests "normalizing" the country name a bit just in case you have both `Thailand` and `thailand` (which would be *separate* properties in JavaScript, since JavaScript is case-sensitive). It's a good idea. At the very least, I would make the name all-lower-case, and his/her suggestion is to remove spaces as well, which is probably a good idea and unlikely to create confusion. If you want the names for display purposes, you could store the first one you see (without making it lower case and removing spaces) in a separate map:

```
realCountry = /*...get the real country name...*/;
country = country.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '_');
if (!mungedNameMap.hasOwnProperty(country)) {
    mungedNameMap[country] = realCountry;
}
```

Then looking up the "munged" name in `mungedNameMap` will give you the first un-munged version you saw.

Comment: Awesome answer! You are the man, T.J.!

Comment: I would also remove spaces and turn the country to lowercase just in case the OPs database have irregularities, plus is not like this will make any difference

Comment: I don't get this answer at all unfortunately.

Comment: @Tommie what don't you get? He told you how to create an object that stores each countries totals.

Comment: @Tommie: Unfortunately, the answer had a really bad editing error for several minutes; hit refresh and see if it's clearer now I've fixed the serious code error that resulted. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'd first get the data in a format that you can play with in js:

```
var data = [
  {country: 'Thailand', city: 'Asia', number: 25},
  {country: 'Thailand', city: 'Bangkok', number: 12},
  {country: 'China', city: 'Wenzhou', number: 1},
  {country: 'Australia', city: 'Sydney', number: 2},
  {country: 'Vietnam', city: 'Saigon', number: 4},
  {country: 'China', city: 'Beijing', number: 3},
  {country: 'USA', city: 'New', number: 4},
  {country: 'USA', city: 'Miami', number: 2}
]
```

Once you have that,  you can sum the number for matching countries:

```
var counts = {};
for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
   var row = data[i];
   counts[row.country] = (counts[row.country] || 0) + 1;
}
```

or, if you wanted a more functional approach, you could use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```
var counts = data.reduce(function(memo, row){
   memo[row.country] = (memo[row.country] || 0) + 1;
   return memo;
},{});
```

Comment: Seems to make sort of sense however i need to push the values into the data array and then it sort of becomes a loop in a loop i a loop?

Check the jsfiddle at:
**[link](http://jsfiddle.net/dwv6s/)**